# Map a Table And a Stored Procedure To Same Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I'm looking for a way to map a Table which return straight data and a Stored Procedure which returns exactly same kind of data with a customized filtration of data to same model, and make 2 DbSet for them... Is there any way to do that? how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be 100% sure, but if you call MapToStoredProcedure:

modelBuilder.Entity().MapToStoredProcedures()

it will change the behavior of the whole method.
so you can only define *below* once:

```
public virtual DbSet<YourEntity> TableAccessor { get; set; }
```

I mean you change the mapping on Entity it self, not it's handler `TableAccessor`

so you cant bind it, but you still can call and retrieve data from the same model using stored procedure or command:

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntity>("my SQL command")
```

as i got this is the only was, and as no one helped during this whole time, i think i'm correct, there is no other way, not till version 6.x of EF.